# Error mirroring a git repo from Bitbucket to Github

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I'm following this guide to setup a mirror from my private Bitbucket repo to a private Github repo.

https://medium.com/@dmitryshaposhnik/sync-bitbucket-repo-to-github-669458ea9a5e

Basically the guide involves setting up a bitbucket pipeline as follows:

```
clone:
  depth: full

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: 'Mirror to Github repo....'
        script:
          - git push --mirror git@github.com:my-repo/repo.git
```

I have it (kinda) working, but the pipeline fails due to the following:

`! [remote rejected] master (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master)`

So it looks like the `git push --mirror` command first deletes all branches, is that correct?

I understand why the master delete won't work (not allowed unless it's an github admin) and I don't want to change the master etc.

I simply want to pipeline all git events on the bitbucket repo over to the github repo.

Anyone know how to do this without hitting this issue?

Separately, I know I could do this by adding another remove to the repo locally and then pushing from there, but I'm looking for a solution that can be handled server side to make it simple for the rest of my team to not have to start manually adding second remotes etc.

Comment: Have you tried `git push git@github.com:my-repo/repo.git --all`? (»Push all branches (i.e. refs under refs/heads/)«)

Comment: @knittl - thanks for that! That at least stops the remote rejected error :) I guess if I do a one off import of the entire repo into Github then that method might work then for all commits going forward.

Comment: But I'm not sure if that includes or excludes tag references (it definitely excludes remote-tracking branches)

Comment: `git push --mirror` means: push all branches that I have locally and *delete* all branches that I *don't* have locally. You may well have only one branch locally, since `git clone` creates a new repository by copying all the commits and *no* branches. (Then it creates *one* branch in the clone.)

Comment: (Note that pipelines generally operate on a clone of the hosted repository, not directly on the hosted repository. Every hosting site is different here and I haven't used Bitbucket but I suspect they work the same as GitHub here. There are some obvious engineering tradeoffs with trying to work directly: in particular, if you offer a forking system, you won't want to allow arbitrary user processes to access the "real" repos.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

```
  default:
    - step:
        name: 'mirror repo'
        script:
          - git clone --mirror "${BITBUCKET_GIT_SSH_ORIGIN}" ./mirrored;
          - cd ./mirrored;
          - git fetch -p --tags origin;
          - git push --mirror "git@github.com:you/target-repo.git"
```